# Getting CultureInfo from RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, regioninfo

In db I already have stored values with RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName values. Atm I have values like 'be' for Belgium, 'no', 'gb', 'en' etc.

If I write:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("be");
```

instead of Belgium, I get Belarus.

So I need a way to get CultureInfo from RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.

Comment: Perhaps you could start from [How to get the list of regions using system .globalization namspace](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/407031/How-to-get-the-list-of-regions-using-system-global), or [this](https://justinchronicles.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/how-to-get-list-of-countries-defined-in-iso-3166-1-programatically-by-c-shar/) one.

Answer (score 1):

Given a two letter region name, there are multiple cultures that can be associated with that region name (because in a country multiple languages can be spoken). For example for Switzerland there are 4 cultures: de, fr, it, rm.

And now some code:

```
public static ILookup<string, CultureInfo> RegionToCultures()
{
    // All the local cultures
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

    // We "group" the cultures by their TwoLetterISORegionName
    return cultures.ToLookup(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID).TwoLetterISORegionName);
}
```

The code returns a `ILookup<string, CultureInfo>` (consider it to be a `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<CultureInfo>>`).

Use it like:

```
var rtoc = RegionToCultures();
```

and then:

```
var switzerlandCultures = rtoc["CH"];

foreach (CultureInfo culture in switzerlandCultures)
{
    Console.WriteLine(culture.EnglishName);
}
```

Note that a `ILookup<,>` **won't** throw an exception if used with a non-existing key: `rtoc["aaaaa"]` will simply return an empty `IEnumerable<>`.